# Can AWS Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator (RIE) emulate asynchronous mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm making an AWS Lambda function that will be called through API Gateway. It will have to be run in asynchronous mode as the processing time will exceed the maximum API Gateway timeout (29s).

Also I'm using the [AWS Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator (RIE)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html) to test my AWS Lambda function locally. To locally test the asynchronous mode, I tried setting the `X-Amz-Invocation-Type: Event` HTTP header to my request, [as we would have to do on the real API Gateway environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html).

However this don't seem to have any effect in the local environment with RIE.

Did I miss something? Is this something that is not supported by the RIE? The docs don't mention anything about that.